# Tranfer files from Ubuntu phone to Mac OS

Tags: ubuntu-touch, macosx, phone, macbook-pro, meizu-mx4

I connected my Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition to my MacBook Pro running OS X via USB cable. My Mac does not see the Ubuntu phone as an external drive. How can I transfer files between the 2?

Comment: Update. I tried to use the application "Android File Transfer". When I connect the Meizu I can see the files on my phone but my entire MacBook Pro freezes and I have to restart. It works well with regular android.